# Why does Spreadsheet::XLSX::Utility2007's xls2csv round off to two decimal places?

Tags: perl, excel, csv, decimal, rounding

I am writing a Perl/Tk script which displays Excel worksheets using the ss2tk example script from the Spreadsheet::Read module. It does not round off two decimal places but the function from [Spreadsheet::XLSX::Utility2007](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Spreadsheet-XLSX) does round off to two decimal places. Why? I'm trying to use that second function as a feature of my program to offer conversion of the displayed worksheets to CSV files.

Comment: This question is too complicated.  Can you reduce the problem to a short code snippet and post that?  Or at least link to the example script and/or the CPAN module perldoc?

Comment: Also posted here: http://www.mahalo.com/answers/programming/in-perl-the-xls2csv-function-from-spreadsheetxlsxutility2007-rounds-off-to-two-decimal-places-why

Comment: Did you ask the module's author?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see you were able to [get an answer](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=734666) over at PerlMonks with the help of [frieduck](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=734666) (any relation to [friedo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/20745/friedo)?), so I'm linking it up for the benefit of SO folks.

To summarize, basically it turned out that the internals of  [Spreadsheet::XLSX::Utility2007](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Spreadsheet-XLSX-0.1/lib/Spreadsheet/XLSX/Utility2007.pm) were automatically applying a 2-decimal place format when retrieving the cell values.  The two workarounds proposed were:

1. [Changing the way the module generates cell types](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=761577) (make it treat them all as defaults) by modifying XLSX internals.
2. [Changing the way the module treats the cells loaded from the spreadsheet](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=761576) (treating them as having the unformatted value from the original spreadsheet), also by modifying internals.

Either way, it was also mentioned that you'd probably be best off defining a `local` sub to do perform the modified behavior, so that there aren't any nasty surprises resulting from changing the module in place.

Comment: It appears that frieduck has **no** relation to friedo.